# Using checkboxes to specify items in array

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I want to use checkboxes to specify the items to be added to an array, my code is as follows:

```
$columns = array(
if (isset($_POST['CustomerID'])) {
   'Customer ID' => 'CustomerID', 
}
  if (isset($_POST['First_name'])) {
     'First Name' => 'First_name',
}
);
```

How can I make this work?
Many thanks

Comment: what is not working here ?

Comment: Don't put your conditional statements inside your array-syntax?

Comment: You should check the manual, especially the `Creating/modifying with square bracket syntax` section: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: I cant have the conditional statements inside the array-syntax. But i need the custom indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use if statements inside of your array, move it outside like so.

```
$columns = array();

if (isset($_POST['CustomerID'])) {
    $columns['Customer ID'] = 'CustomerID';
}

if (isset($_POST['First_name'])) {
    $columns['First Name'] = 'First_name';
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be:
if (isset($_POST['CustomerID'])) {
    $columns['Customer ID'] = $_POST['CustomerID'];
}

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['CustomerID'])) {
    array_push($columns, 'Customer ID');
}
    // OR for those that like slight performance increases
if (isset($_POST['CustomerID'])) {
    $columns[] = 'Customer ID';
}
```

You could try this? You wouldn't have your custom indexing, you would have to address `$columns[0]`, `$columns[1]` etc but ultimately it only contains the content you require.

Comment: That works, but i really could do with the custom indexing because im using them as the headers for the columns. is there no way to do this?

Comment: Then view this post: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php#106717 and swap array_push() for array_put_to_position() and add in the relevant parameters.